# jquery slideDown/slideUp sees all radio button values as same

Tags: jquery

I have used this a couple times and it usually works great.  However, in my latest usage the hidden div will slide down just fine, but wont go back up.  It is supposed to slide down when the 'Yes' radio button is clicked, and back up when No is clicked.  At this time it will slide down regardless of the radio button clicked, and will not slide up.  I assume it always seeing a 'Yes' value..

Here is html:

```
    <div id="AliasSectionTop">
        Have you ever been known by another name (maiden name, name change, etc)?
        <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="aliasName" />Yes
        <input type="radio" value="No" name="aliasName" />No
    </div>

    <div id="AliasSectionBottom" class="hidden">

        @for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            <div class="formGroup">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.Label("First Name")
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonAliasModel[i].FirstNameAlias)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="formGroup">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.Label("Last Name")
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonAliasModel[i].LastNameAlias)
                </div>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
```

Here is jquery:

```
    // SHow full form once the waiver checkboix is checked.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name=aliasName]").click(function () {
            if ($("input[name=aliasName]").val() == "Yes") {
                $("#AliasSectionBottom").slideDown(800);
            } else {
                $("#AliasSectionBottom").slideUp("fast");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `if($("input[name=aliasName]").val() == "Yes"){` to `if($(this).val() == "Yes"){` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if ($("input[name=aliasName]").val() == "Yes")
```

There are 2 elements in the collection `$("input[name='aliasName']")`. jQuery can only return one value so it will always be the first one in the collection so your `if` is always true.

You could filter the selector using `:checked` selector:

```
if ($("input[name='aliasName']:checked").val() == "Yes")
```